# How to use PHP for form validation?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

Well, I have the following problem: my little test website is near completion and all that’s left is PHP validation on submit. But there exactly lies my problem. I can’t seem to let it validate when the user clicks submit.

I searched plenty of websites but on all of those they submit the page to the same page, and I submit the page to a new page. I don’t know how different this is from the first method but I can’t seem to get it to work.

I have 5 fields in my form which need to be required:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Naam:</td>
        <td align="left"><input type="text" name="naam" onkeydown="return names(event)"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Woonplaats:</td>
        <td align="left"><input type="text" name="woonplaats" onkeydown="return names(event)"/></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="right">Straatnaam:</td>
        <td align="left"><input type="text" name="straatnaam" onkeydown="return names(event)"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Huisnummer:</td>
        <td align="left"><input type="text" class="formnumbers" name="huisnummer"/></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Telefoonnummer:</td>
        <td align="left"><input type="text" name="telefoonnummer" onkeydown="return phonenumber(event)"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

That’s all. My form action is as follows:

```
<form action="?page=pizza_bestelling" method="post" name="orderform">
```

I know PHP validation should be really easy (at least that’s what I’ve heard) but I can’t seem to work it out myself, so that’s why I decided to ask it here.

Now all it needs to do is check if one of those 5 fields is empty, if so don’t submit. Otherwise submit.

(Keep in mind that I have 16 fields in my form, it counts only for these 5 specific, the other 11 can be empty)

I appreciate any help in this matter, since it’s all that’s left before completing my website!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need Javascript to validate form elements _before_ submitting, this can't be done with PHP since it runs on the server, not in your browser.

Comment: so what is happening though?  Where's your server side code?  And is the form POSTing correctly?  i.e. in the network tab of your console you see the POST going out as a 200?  Is all the data from the form in the POST body of the request?  What debugging are you doing on the server side?  What do you get if you var_dump $_POST?

Comment: @thescientist when i fill in some information and press submit i get send to pizza_bestelling and i have an array with all the information an foreach to print it on the website, all is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Upon submiting you will lose "?page=pizza_bestelling" of the link, you can set it in a hidden input with that value if you need it passed.

set the method to method="post" in the form

and on the same page you will need something like

```
function validate_form($data)
{
   //rules that will end with  return false; if they are not valid
   // example
   if (!isset($data["naam"]) || $data["naam"] == '') return false; // if the name is not set or it's empty

   // return true if all validation checks are passed
   return true;
}


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST")
{
   $form_data['naam'] = $_POST['naam'];
   $form_data['woonplaats'] = $_POST['woonplaats'];
   // and so forth for each variable

   // run the validate_form function for the data you got through POST
   validate_form($form_data);

}else
{
 //form displayed here

}
```

Comment: How OP can lose `?page=pizza_bestelling` after submitting? It will be in $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Comment: `if (!isset($data["naam"] || $data["naam"] == '')` you seem to miss a ) somewhere am i right? my code won't work on that line, gives an error

Comment: @ voodoo417 try the code, he has a query string in it, not an actual php file to which it points, wasn't sure myself so I tested it before posting the comment - in his case having action="?page=pizza_bestellin" or action="" it's the same thing.

Comment: I don't know if I should be adding something myself except the other variables $form_data since i did that, but when i fill in no fields and press submit i get send to pizza_bestelling anyway.


PS: You misspelled METHOD (METHDO)

Comment: set it to action="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF];?>" and also add in the form <input type="hidden" name="page" value="pizza_bestselling" unless that page does exists and you are using a MVC framework like (ci/smarty/zend) in which case you are doing it completly wrong :)

Comment: are you running this script on a file named "pizza_bestelling.php" ?

Comment: No i am not, i run it on the order page, and if the submit goes through it needs to be send to pizza_bestelling and when the submit fails, doesnt meet the requirements (those 5 required fields) it needs to stay on the same page and show me the errors.

Comment: did you set action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" in the form and deleted action="?page=pizza_bestelling" ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up an `errors` array which will store any errors, and allow you to print them out if necessary.

Then you check each variable in the following manner:

```
$errors = array(); //initialise error array

if (empty($_POST['naam'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to add a name';
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['naam']);
    }
```

This checks if the `naam` input and writes a message to the errors array if it's empty, or assigns the value to the `$name` variable if not.

Once you've gone through all your inputs, you can then perform a check on the errors array:

```
if (empty($errors)) { // If everything's OK.
 //do what you need to do
} else {
echo '<p>The following errors occurred:<br/>';
        foreach ($errors as $msg) {
            echo "$msg<br/>\n";
        }
        echo '<p>Please try again</p>';
    }
```

This only checks for empty fields of course - you should implement more validation for valid emails etc. For useability purposes you should really look at  a one-page solution with sticky fields though.

Answer (score 0):

Do a for each as follows:

```
$allowed = array("naam","woonplaats","stratnaam","formnumbers","telefoonnummer");
foreach ($allowed as $key => $val){
  if($_POST[$key] == "")
    $errors = true;
}
if($errors){
  // don't submit
}
else {
  // submit 
}
```

Comment: I feel kinda stupid for asking, but what do i need to fill in within the `don't submit` and `submit`? =S